# Get max with one count

Tags: sql

I use a sql request to get the number message by user by forum.

```
SELECT count(idpost), iduser, idforum
FROM post
group by iduser, idforum
```

And I get this result:
[image]

But I want to get the better poster in one forum. How can I get it?
I want to get the user who has the most number of post in ONE forum like this : 
[image]

Comment: why "select count(idpost),idforum from post group by idforum" doesnt work? What do u exactly want? Please put the example result u want

Comment: I need the id of the better poster. With this request I get all poster and their count of post

Comment: what do u mean: "id of the better poster"

Comment: Show us the expected result!

Comment: What about if 2 people have posted the same amount of times in a forum?

Comment: You want each forum's top poster, incl count?

Comment: exactly what I need!

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support `ROW_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the edited question:

Please try the query below. What we need is a subquery finding max(idpost) based on idforum. Think the query below:

```
select max(idpost) as IDPOST,idforum 
from post
group by idforum
```

What this query is supposed to do is to find the number of posts by a user on a forum. So it should present you an output like:

```
idpost  idforum
3       1
2       2
3       4
```

Then we need to find the related iduser for this rows as:

```
select p2.IDPOST, p1.iduser, p2.idforum
from post p1 inner join
                ( --the query above comes here as subquery.
                 select max(idpost) as IDPOST,idforum 
                 from post
                 group by idforum
                ) p2 on p1.idforum = p2.idforum and p1.idpost = p2.IDPOST
```

What it is doing is to match the data from your main table with the temprorary data coming from your subquery based on idforum and idpost values and adding iduser value from your original table.

```
idpost iduser idforum
3      2      1
2      6      2
3      2      4
```

Comment: Probably what OP is asking for!

Comment: Well, I wrote there idpost because in your original query u are using idpost, so there should be a column like that. If not, please use the name of the column regarding to the number of post (its name is 'count', maybe?)

Comment: The important point here is for you to understand the query logic. I am sure you can change the column names into the proper ones once you understand the logic.

Comment: Your sub-request :
select max(idpost) as IDPOST,idforum 
from post
group by idforum
get the number of post in every form. But I need the user who has post the greater number of message/post.

Comment: I updated my answer by detailing more for u to understand. I tested my code on my pc also and it is working.

Comment: Your query returns a single post with *the highest postid* for a forum, but the OP wanted to get the user with *the highest number* of posts per forum.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(idpost) MAX,iduser,idforum FROM post
ORDER BY count(idpost) DESC group by iduser,idforum
```

Or, you can do a nested query. But, I prefer this.
You can easily pick the first result as MAX

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(CN),idforum,Max(iduser) iduser
FROM (
   SELECT count(idpost) CN,iduser,idforum 
   FROM post
   Group By iduser,idforum 
)  A Group By idforum
```

Comment: @bizard Plz check now

Comment: I get the user with the greater iduser. But I want to get the user who has the most nuber of post....

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming you supply the idForum of the forum in question.........just get the top row of your query ordered by the count desc

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
   (
    SELECT count(idpost),iduser,idforum FROM post
    GROUP BY iduser,idforum 
   ) PostsCount
WHERE PostsCount.idForum = @theForumIdIamLookingFor
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: TOP is product specific, and no dbms has been specified.

Comment: Agreed - Also - Its would miss a scenario where there is a tie.

What does the OP want to do with ties?

Answer (score 1):

If your DBMS supports RANK/ROW_NUMBER it simple:

```
select cnt, iduser, idforum
from
 (
   SELECT count(idpost) as cnt, iduser, idforum, 
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY idforum ORDER BY count(idpost) DESC) as rnk
   FROM post
   group by iduser, idforum 
 ) dt
where rnk = 1
```

This might return more than one row per forum if multiple users share the same count. Switch to ROW_NUMBER if you want to return only one (but random) row.